# Why is my post still on hold after several edits?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Following the procedure states [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions), I'm creating this post to bring to your attention to my post that is still on hold since two days without any further information despite my several edit.

[Div with text height animation from bottom](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175135/div-with-text-height-animation-from-bottom)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From box below your question

> Questions containing broken code or asking for advice about code not yet written are off-topic

Your question has

> Try changing top 0 to Bottom 0 for the .text:after and see the issue

so at least partially it is about broken code.

See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

> What types of questions should I avoid asking?
>
> (...)
>
> Troubleshooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
>
> Code Review is for open-ended questions about code that already works correctly (to the best of your knowledge). Questions seeking help about debugging or understanding code are off-topic for Code Review, and may be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

See also [I think my code might have a bug, but I am not sure if it actually does, is it broken code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8446/i-think-my-code-might-have-a-bug-but-i-am-not-sure-if-it-actually-does-is-it-b?cb=1)

> The purpose of the "no broken code" rule is to avoid turning reviewers into bug-hunters. It's about what the intent of your post is: if you want to improve your code in every aspect, you're at the right place. If you want to fix a specific issue with your code, you'd better ask on SO.